# How to write Junit Test case for particular log statement in a particular Method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, microservices, junit5

How to write Junit test case for Log statement which is written inside a method in service or controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `OutputCaptureExtension` which will capture all things that are printed out by `System.out` and `System.err`. An example is :

```
@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void theTest(CapturedOutput output) {
        FooService fooService = new FooService();
        fooService.doSomthing();

        assertThat(output.getOut()).contains("bar");
    }

}
```

It will then expect that `fooService.doSomthing()` will print out some logging statements which contains the word "bar" to `System.out`